# match with a String and retrive all available strings with local databases in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three columns in my local database

```
Name    Meaning    Gender
-------------------------
pavan   god        male    
pappy   beauty     male    
lokesh  handsome   male
```

I want all Names starting with "P" and their meaning and gender also. How can I retrieve that?

Comment: Explain more about your problem

Comment: i have edited above one is my problem how the way cursor is used to that problem

Comment: What codes have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Android, But I know SQL and SQLite. So I consider that you can run queries. And the only thing you want is just the query itself (As you haven't mention where is your exact problem.)

```
select * from tableName where Name like '%P'
```

Comment: it is not working.when i use below code it will retrive all values

Comment: your query will working in SQL but in my app it will retirve all fields in the database

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query("tableName", new String[]{"Name", "Meaning", "Gender"}
                  , "Name LIKE " + "'P%'", null, null, null, null);

    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        // your code to use values
    }
```

To get more details regarding how to use cursors and sqlite in android, please refer this link:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: boss i pass my string in the place of P in the above code but it getting all data Instead of starting with P